# Difficulty connecting to a WPA2 Enterprise network, then disconnects after 20-30 minutes

Tags: 11.04, wireless

My University is using a WPA2 Enterprise network, it has these properties:

Authentication: `PEAP (Version 0)`
Inner Authentication: `MSCHAPv2`

Connecting to the wifi is almost impossible all the time. But sometimes it does connect. But only stays connected for 20-30 minutes, and then disconnects.

I'll post the output of nm-tool too, just in case. (While connected to the Home network, it gives no trouble).

When searching the forums, it seemed that this was a common issue, but through hours of searching I couldn't find a solution. If anyone knows of any fix, please let me know.

- Output of nm-tool follows.

  ```
  - Device: wlan0  [Home] --------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlagn
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        AC:72:89:3A:71:95

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           54 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes
  ```
- Output of: `uname -a`

> Linux vostro 2.6.38-11-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 29 19:02:55 UTC
>   2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: have you tried any alternative such as `wicd` or `connman` ?

Comment: @yasith - are you sure its an encryption issue - could be an MTU issue as per my answer here?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/59335/why-does-my-wifi-randomly-disconnect/60321#60321

Comment: @sagarchalise I tried wicd today, didn't seem to work out. It's interesting to note that it always connects when I turn the computer on, when I'm in the wifi zone.

Comment: @fossfreedom Thank you for the link. I will try that tomorrow at uni.

It's hard to debug the issue, because at uni, I don't have wifi, and at home, I don't have the buggy connection. It would be great if anyone of you can direct me towards how to debug this issue.

Comment: I looked into the MTU, and it's already at the auto setting.

Here's the output of dmesg

http://pastebin.com/cAUcbzxU

Comment: Is your problem coincident with closing/opening the lid, suspend or hibernate? See `/var/log/pm-*.log` and my answer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/65632/why-is-wireless-down-strange-after-switching-to-battery

Comment: No, it has no connections with closing/opening the lid. I tried turning off the power save thing. Didn't work.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: The problem still applies and I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: @yasith What about the first comment? Did you try an alternative as suggested?

Comment: @nitstorm I tried them too. Had no luck.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: @BlueXrider Nope not looking for an answer, didn't solve it though. I'm now using my android phone to connect to wifi and, tether it using a USB connection. Not very convenient, but works.