# Disappearing and reappearing ethernet connection

Tags: 10.04, ethernet

I have internet via ethernet cable plugged in directly into my desktop machine; windows and ubuntu on the same machine.

The problem is that after loggin in internet is working (though the speed is less than on Windows) for about 10 mins, after which connection disappears: cannot `ping` anything, `nslookup` is not responding too. Then after about 10 mins connection is back.

---

I'm not much familiar with Ubuntu, sorry if some info is missing. I have

```
Ubuntu version: 10.04.4 LTS
Codename: lucid
```

(for some reason I have to stay on `10.04` and cannot upgrade to a newer version now)

Network interfaces:

```
~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Ethernet controller:

```
~$lspci -v
...
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8432
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
        I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
        Memory at f2104000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Memory at f2100000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
...
```

Comment: Currently I'm using my friend's computer and it has the same problem.

Ubuntu 13.04 32bit

Comment: Paste `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` contents.

Comment: Anything in logs after the disconnect?

Comment: @ilhan I believe you should have asked your own question instead placing a bounty over this one. Hardware problems are preferred in the basis of 1 question per person per combination of hardware and kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this already by changing kernel driver version from r8169 to r8168.
http://www.foxhop.net/realtek-dropping-packets-on-linux-ubuntu-and-fedora

Comment: @ilhan, please try it and write if it helps

Answer (score 2):

1. Update your system, esp the Kernel. Reboot and check now.
2. If it's still not solved, try getting a more stable driver like the R8168B:

   - Download the R8168B linux driver:

     - older version: `wget http://www.foxhop.net/attachment/r8168-8.023.00.tar.bz2
       tar vjxf r8168-8.023.00.tar.bz2`
     - or get the latest version from [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com/search/default.aspx?keyword=r8168).
   - Check whether the built-in driver, r8169.ko (or r8169.o for kernel 2.4.x), is installed:
     `lsmod | grep r8169`
   - R8169 seems installed if the lsmod command returns output, so remove r8169 with:
     `sudo rmmod r8169`
   - Install the Realtec r8168b nic driver:
     `cd r8168-8.023.00`
     `sudo ./autorun.sh`
   - Prevent the r8169 driver from loading again:
     `echo "blacklist r8169" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
   - You may now verify that r8168b has been installed and loaded by running:
     `lsmod | grep r8168`
   - To avoid R8169 driver returning after reboots, clean the cache using the following command:
     `update-initramfs -u`

Source: [Realtek NIC driver r8169 dropping packets on linux ubuntu and fedora](http://www.foxhop.net/realtek-dropping-packets-on-linux-ubuntu-and-fedora)