# I need help with my intel wifi 7260. Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, asus, intel, intel-wireless

nice day.

I have an Asus C300MA Dh2 (chromebook), and im trying install the new ubuntu 16.04 because i think can get a better kernel.

When i try install, i can't because the installer tell me i have an error. The only form i can intalls is using internet.

Now, my problem is, i can't connect to the internet. I click, and charge, but in 4 seconds say's "disconected, now you are offline"

I don't know what i can i do. Please help me. PD: Sorry for my english, i need improve. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Confirming that this issue affects multiple users and is apparently fixed in an upstream Kernel: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1578610

Answer (score 1):

I know this will sound completely ridiculous but....

**What I Tried**

Updating all the Linux Firmware drivers

- Tried to boot using a backup Kernel (4.2.x).
- Tried using two Mainline, upstream Kernels (4.6.x-wily and 4.4.10-Xenial).
- Tried blacklisting `acer-wmi`.
- Tried setting `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` to add `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`.
  Tried also adding `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8` to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`.

Nothing worked.

**What worked for me?**

1. Disable your Wireless Settings by Clicking that Wirless button off (I'm using Cinnamon, same principle for Unity)

[image: Disable Wirless]

2. From the same Menu, click "Network Connections"
3. Delete everything.
4. Reboot
5. Renable Wireless
6. Reconnect to your wireless network

**Results**

Haven't had a connection issue in nearly an hour. I'll update it if I have any further issues. Seriously, I never thought in a million years this would do anything but as desperate enough to try the obvious. It worked.

Tried from this suggestion here: 
[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/288630/419666)