# RT3290 Wireless stops working randomly until reboot.

Tags: wireless, 13.10, ralink

My wifi stops working randomly till I reboot my laptop.

I dont know if this helps :

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280 
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/59335/why-does-my-wifi-randomly-disconnect

Answer (score 0):

Yup.

6 years old problem...

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1333994.html
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/132042

It's been reported multiple times and the ubuntu developers couldn't care less.

Having the exact same problem since forever and I doubt I'll live to see the day it gets fixed.

Your wireless whatever doesn't matter, it happens on everything (realtek, intel, atheros etc)

Only "workaround" I could find so far was to remove and reload the modules. It's beyond pathetic.

Comment: What about [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/253660/75166)?